# getting database values using get_object_or_404

Tags: django

I am using `get_object_or_404` to try to get a list of values from my database. I'm trying to filter the `get_object_or_404` function for the state variable to grab only values that are associated with the `disease_id`. The code below does not work (it grabs all values in the State table. Any ideas?

*views.py*

```
def option(request, disease_id, state_id):

    state = get_object_or_404(State, relevantdisease=disease_id)
    disease = get_object_or_404(Disease, pk=disease_id)

    context = {'state': state, 'disease':disease }
    return render(request, "option.html", context)
```

*models.py*

```
class State(models.Model):
    state = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='state')
    relevantdisease = models.ForeignKey(Disease, verbose_name="disease")
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`get_object_or_404` will only return one object. You need [`get_list_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404) as there could be multiple states for one disease:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404, get_object_or_404

def option(request, disease_id, state_id):

    state = get_list_or_404(State, relevantdisease__pk=disease_id)
    disease = get_object_or_404(Disease, pk=disease_id)

    context = {'state': state, 'disease':disease }
    return render(request, "option.html", context)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised that's not 404'ing, actually.  Try this:

```
state = get_object_or_404(State, relevantdisease_id=disease_id)
```

Or, if you prefer, this:

```
disease = get_object_or_404(Disease, pk=disease_id)
state = get_object_or_404(State, relevantdisease=disease)
```

The point is that the `relevantdisease` field expects filters to use the actual `Disease` model, not the PK.  You can use the PK if you filter on the implicit ID field, as in my first example, or fetch a Disease object and filter using that.  The latter would be inefficient if you didn't need the Disease instance anyway, but your example shows you retrieving it regardless so fetching it first won't cost you any performance.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing something with your models.

You have `ForeighKey()` with `Disease` in `State` model. What that means is there are *many* `State`s for *one* `Disease`.

So when you do `get_object_or_404(State, relevantdisease_id=disease_id)` you will get all `State` objects for that `disease_id`.

You may want to use `get_list_or_404()` and work with either the list of `State` objects or choose one with whatever criteria you want.